# is it possible to collect \section's in \mainpage?

Tags: doxygen

I need to present documentation with a substantial `\mainpage`, but I would like keep the various `\section`, `\subsection`, etc. near the code implementing them.

The best I could do is to mark the various fragments with `\page` and include them with `\subpage`.

This is suboptimal because it actually creates another page (unsurprisingly!) while I would like to have sections/subsections inline.

What I have now is:

- a `\mainpage` with some text and a bunch of

  - `\subpage xxx`
- documentation scattered around in the sources including:

  - `\file` per-file documentation.
  - class/function/whatever specific documentation.
  - occasional `\page xxx` to be referenced in `\mainpage`.

This works and I can construct meaningful documentation.

Problem is `\subpage` construct generates a new page (in HTML) or a separate chapter (in LaTeX/PDF); I would like to be able to control it better and possibly to put all "subpages" together in the same "chapter" as if I used `\section`, `\subsection` and similar constructs.

Current structure is kind-of-OK in HTML, but quickly becomes unmanageable in LaTeX, especially if I start using `\subpage` links in subpages to simulate `\subsection`, `\subsubsection` and friends.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Doxygen has the `GENERATE_TREEVIEW` that gives an overview of all types of pages and sections. When you want to have a list on your mainpage for the sections you could use the `\ref` command (like you showed with `\subpage` for pages).

Comment: @albert: I'm on bleeding edge (1.9.5). I am looking for some way to include directly in mainpage, not in a list I have to click on. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean with " am looking for some way to include directly in mainpage" ? do you want to include the section "verbatim" into the main page? I the later case maybe the `\include{doc}` or `\snippet{doc}` could help.

Comment: @albert: I updated OP to better explain what I need.

Comment: I think that you should indeed look at `\include{doc}` or `\snippet{doc}`, some problems might occur with nesting `\include{doc}` or `\snippet{doc}` (I didn't try though).